# Who and where in Act 1 are the merchants that sell dyes?

Tags: diablo-iii-console

I know you can get dye in Act 1, but who and where are the people that sell it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's sold by a merchant who is Accessible after the quest where you save Deckard Cain. He is right behind the tavern.

[image]

**It's the one the red arrow is pointing at not the Gem**

As Alok has mentioned in the comments, there are also two randomly spawning merchants in Act I.

The first one is [The Wandering Tinker](http://www.diablowiki.net/Wandering_Tinker) which spawns Here:

[image]

And the second one is [Rodger The Alchemist](http://www.diablowiki.net/Rodger_the_Alchemist) who can be found here:

[image]

Comment: You should add the guy on bridge before the spider cavern (who sells at half price, at least in PC version).

Comment: Yeah but he isn't there all the time. I only found him twice so far (well I gotta admit tho that I usually don't farm in act 1)

Comment: He appears randomly, but its better to include that for a complete answer. Also, he is far cheaper, and may have different dyes in stock.